# Unable to return custom not-found page when using next.js v13.4 custom layouts

Tags: error-handling, next.js13, custom-error-pages

I have been using RootLayout for all my pages and not-found.jsx works perfectly but I switched to custom Layouts to achieve different UIs and default 404 page is now showing instead of custom not-found page I specified.

I created a not-found.jsx file in the custom folder where I have my page.jsx for the homepage and below is the content of the not-found.jsx file

import styles from './notfound.module.scss';
const NotFound = () => {
return (

### Page Not Found

The page you are trying to access does not exist or may have been
moved permanently.

);
};

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.